# Mejorar procedimiento almacenado para recorrer códigos de un textbox multiline

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día muchachos tratare de ser lo mas claro y breve para obtener ayuda
tengo un procedimiento almacenado que se llama *sp_comparar* que recibe solo un parámetro @CODPRO este recibe códigos que el usuario pega en un *textbox multiline* en visual basic, el error que tiene la aplicacion es que solo ejecuta un código y muestra el resultado pero cuando le envió 2 o mas códigos me dice lo siguiente:

> has too many arguments specified

Justo en la línea `adaptador.Fill(dt)`.

Les adjunto el código del procedimiento almacenado y de visual para obtener de ustedes una guía o solución a esto que llevo días tratando de resolver:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_Comparar](@CODPRO as varchar(max)) ---procedimiento para ponerlo en visual basic 
as
 Declare @CODPRO_CURSOR                 as varchar(18),
         @CODPRO_TABLA                  as varchar(18),
         @DESCRIPCION_CURSOR            as varchar(80),
         @DESCRIPCION_TABLA             as varchar(80),
         @PRECIO_CURSOR                 as decimal(10,2),
         @PRECIO_TABLA                  as decimal(10,2),
         @UNI_MED_BASE_CURSOR           as varchar(7),
         @UNI_MED_BASE_TABLA            as varchar(7),
         @UPC_CURSOR                    as varchar(25),
         @UPC_TABLA                     as varchar(25),
         @BLOQUEADO_CURSOR              as varchar(10),
         @BLOQUEADO_TABLA               as varchar(10),
         @CORRELATIVO_CURSOR            as integer  

begin -- Begin principal
 
 -- Limpiar tabla comparativa
    truncate table tblComparar

 -- insertar en tabla tblComparar de acuerdo al parámetro recibido como CODPRO
    insert into tblComparar(CODPRO,DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,UNIDAD_MEDIDA,UPC,BLOQUEADO,COMAYAGUELA,VILLASDELSOL,PRESIDENCIAL)

    select substring(a.CODPRO,11,8) Codigo, Rtrim(a.descripcion) Descripcion, u.precio_base Precio, a.uni_med_base Unidad_Medida, Rtrim(up.upc) Codigo_Barra, a.bloqueado Bloqueado,'','',''
    from ARTICULO a 
    left join upc up on a.CODPRO = up.CODPRO
    left join UNIMEDPRODUCTO u on a.CODPRO = u.CODPRO
    where substring(a.CODPRO,11,8) = @CODPRO
 
  --Crear cursor para procesar la tabla tblComparar registro por registro
    
    declare cursor_comparar cursor for
    select CORRELATIVO,CODPRO,DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,UNIDAD_MEDIDA,UPC,BLOQUEADO --poner todos los campos solicitados
    from tblComparar 

    open cursor_comparar

    -- Lee los registros del cursor
    -- que son registros del servidor pedregal
    fetch next from cursor_comparar into
    @CORRELATIVO_CURSOR,@CODPRO_CURSOR,@DESCRIPCION_CURSOR,@PRECIO_CURSOR,@UNI_MED_BASE_CURSOR,@UPC_CURSOR,@BLOQUEADO_CURSOR
    
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      begin
        -- Comparar con villasdelsol
        
             select @CODPRO_TABLA         = a.codpro, 
                    @DESCRIPCION_TABLA    = a.descripcion, 
                    @PRECIO_TABLA         = u.precio_base, 
                    @UNI_MED_BASE_TABLA   = a.uni_med_base,
                    @UPC_TABLA            = up.upc, 
                    @BLOQUEADO_TABLA      = a.bloqueado
             from srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.ARTICULO a 
             left join srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.UPC up on a.CODPRO = up.CODPRO
             left join srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.UNIMEDPRODUCTO u on a.CODPRO = u.CODPRO
             where substring(a.CODPRO,11,8) = @CODPRO_CURSOR 
             And up.upc = @UPC_CURSOR
            
            
            if @DESCRIPCION_TABLA <> @DESCRIPCION_CURSOR or @PRECIO_TABLA <> @PRECIO_CURSOR or
               @UNI_MED_BASE_TABLA <> @UNI_MED_BASE_CURSOR or @UPC_TABLA <> @UPC_CURSOR or @BLOQUEADO_TABLA <> @BLOQUEADO_CURSOR
               begin
                 update tblComparar         -- Si hay diferencias entonces guardar que no está actualizado 
                 set VILLASDELSOL  = 'NO ACTUALIZADO'
                 where correlativo = @CORRELATIVO_CURSOR 
               end
            else
               begin
                 update tblComparar 
                 set VILLASDELSOL  = 'ACTUALIZADO'
                 where correlativo = @CORRELATIVO_CURSOR
               end

               fetch next from cursor_comparar into
         @CORRELATIVO_CURSOR,@CODPRO_CURSOR,@DESCRIPCION_CURSOR,@PRECIO_CURSOR,@UNI_MED_BASE_CURSOR,@UPC_CURSOR,@BLOQUEADO_CURSOR
    
    end -- End del while

    close cursor_comparar

    deallocate cursor_comparar

     --Desplegamos el resultado
    select CODPRO,DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,UNIDAD_MEDIDA,UPC,BLOQUEADO,COMAYAGUELA,VILLASDELSOL,PRESIDENCIAL from tblComparar 

    

     end   -- End del begin principal


GO
```

Código Visual:

```
Public Class FrmBuscar

    Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
        'Try




        Dim conexion = New SqlConnection("Data Source = xxx; Initial Catalog = pxx; Integrated Security = false; User Id= xxx; Password = xxx;")
        txtCodigo.Focus()

        'llamada a procediento almacenado
        Dim proce As New SqlCommand("sp_Comparar", conexion)
        proce.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter(proce)

        Dim dt = New DataTable     'crea la tabla

        'declaracion del array y la variable que almacena el valor del textbox
        Dim textbox As String
        Dim codigo() As String

        'inicializacion del array y la variable
        textbox = Convert.ToString(txtCodigo.Text)
        codigo = Split(textbox, vbCrLf)

        'uso de for para recorrer el array con los codigos en el textbox
        For i = 0 To UBound(codigo)

            'se establece la condicion si desea ver o no el campo UPC y a la misma vez mostrar el resultado
            If chUPC.Checked = True Then

                proce.CommandTimeout = 300
                proce.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODPRO", codigo(i))
                adaptador.Fill(dt) 'se llena la tabla con la informacion proveniente del adaptador

            Else

                'Dim proce2 As New SqlCommand("sp_Comparar2", conexion)
                'proce2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                'proce2.CommandTimeout = 240
                'proce2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODPRO", codigo(i))
                'Dim adaptador2 As New SqlDataAdapter(proce2)
                'adaptador2.Fill(dt) 'se llena la tabla con la informacion proveniente del adaptador

            End If
        Next

        Me.dgDatos.DataSource = dt
        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    MessageBox.Show("Error al llenar datagridview" + ex.Message)
        'End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Veo el problema.. no se como solucionartelo porque estan mal las dos cosas, el SP y la llamada al SP.. el SP solo recibe de a uno (no hay forma de mandarle mas de a uno).. tu codigo, no limpia nunca los parametros.. asi que como esta en un for, al dar la segunda vuelta, hay dos parametros que se le pasan al SP...

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 problemas con tu código. El primero, y es el que enfrentas aquí, es que estás usando AddWithValue. Eso quiere decir que cada vez que haces una iteración, tratas de agregar un nuevo parámetro en vez de cambiar el valor únicamente. Hay algunos problemas adicionales con esa función ya que además busca adivinar el tipo de dato en vez de que se asigne el correcto.

Esto se puede corregir agregando el parámetro usando Add() y en cada iteración agregar el valor correcto.

```
Public Class FrmBuscar

    Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
        'Try




        Dim conexion = New SqlConnection("Data Source = xxx; Initial Catalog = pxx; Integrated Security = false; User Id= xxx; Password = xxx;")
        txtCodigo.Focus()

        'llamada a procediento almacenado
        Dim proce As New SqlCommand("sp_Comparar", conexion)
        proce.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        proce.Parameters.Add("@CODPRO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 18)
        Dim adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter(proce)

        Dim dt = New DataTable     'crea la tabla

        'declaracion del array y la variable que almacena el valor del textbox
        Dim textbox As String
        Dim codigo() As String

        'inicializacion del array y la variable
        textbox = Convert.ToString(txtCodigo.Text)
        codigo = Split(textbox, vbCrLf)

        'uso de for para recorrer el array con los codigos en el textbox
        For i = 0 To UBound(codigo)

            'se establece la condicion si desea ver o no el campo UPC y a la misma vez mostrar el resultado
            If chUPC.Checked = True Then

                proce.CommandTimeout = 300
                proce.Parameters("@CODPRO").Value = codigo(i)
                adaptador.Fill(dt) 'se llena la tabla con la informacion proveniente del adaptador

            Else

                'Dim proce2 As New SqlCommand("sp_Comparar2", conexion)
                'proce2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                'proce2.CommandTimeout = 240
                'proce2.Parameters.Add("@CODPRO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 18)
                'proce2.Parameters("@CODPRO").Value = codigo(i)
                'Dim adaptador2 As New SqlDataAdapter(proce2)
                'adaptador2.Fill(dt) 'se llena la tabla con la informacion proveniente del adaptador

            End If
        Next

        Me.dgDatos.DataSource = dt
        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    MessageBox.Show("Error al llenar datagridview" + ex.Message)
        'End Try
    End Sub
```

El segundo problema es que usas demasiado código para tu procedimiento. Se puede simplificar, empezando por asignar el tipo de dato correcto para el parámetro.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_Comparar](@CODPRO as varchar(18)) ---procedimiento para ponerlo en visual basic 
as

 ---- Limpiar tabla comparativa
 --   truncate table tblComparar

 ---- insertar en tabla tblComparar de acuerdo al parámetro recibido como CODPRO
 --   insert into tblComparar(CODPRO,DESCRIPCION,PRECIO,UNIDAD_MEDIDA,UPC,BLOQUEADO,COMAYAGUELA,VILLASDELSOL,PRESIDENCIAL)

 -- Al parecer la tabla comparativa no tiene ningún uso fuera de este procedimiento por lo que no necesitamos insertar para mostrar datos
    select substring(a.CODPRO,11,8)                     AS Codigo, 
            Rtrim(a.descripcion)                        AS Descripcion, 
            u.precio_base                               AS Precio, 
            a.uni_med_base                              AS Unidad_Medida, 
            Rtrim(up.upc)                               AS Codigo_Barra, 
            a.bloqueado                                 AS Bloqueado,
            ''                                          AS COMAYAGUELA,
            ISNULL( vs.villasdelsol, 'NO ACTUALIZADO')  AS villasdelsol
            ''                                          AS PRESIDENCIAL
    from ARTICULO a 
    left join upc up on a.CODPRO = up.CODPRO
    left join UNIMEDPRODUCTO u on a.CODPRO = u.CODPRO
    OUTER APPLY ( select CASE  WHEN a.CODPRO        = va.codpro
                               AND  a.DESCRIPCION   = va.descripcion
                               AND  u.precio_base   = vu.precio_base 
                               AND  a.uni_med_base  = va.uni_med_base
                               AND  up.upc          = vup.upc 
                               AND  a.bloqueado     = va.bloqueado 
                                    THEN 'ACTUALIZADO' END AS VILLASDELSOL
                   from      srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.ARTICULO       va 
                   left join srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.UPC            vup on a.CODPRO = up.CODPRO
                   left join srvvillasdelsol.pos_tda.dbo.UNIMEDPRODUCTO vu on a.CODPRO = u.CODPRO
                   where c.CODPRO       = substring(a.CODPRO,11,8) 
                   And c.upc            = up.upc) vs
    where substring(a.CODPRO,11,8) = @CODPRO;


    -- --Desplegamos el resultado
    --select c.CODPRO,
    --       c.DESCRIPCION,
    --       c.PRECIO,
    --       c.UNIDAD_MEDIDA,
    --       c.UPC,
    --       c.BLOQUEADO,
    --       c.COMAYAGUELA,
    --       c.VILLASDELSOL
    --       c.PRESIDENCIAL 
    --from tblComparar c;

GO
```

Comment: gracias Luis haber si entendi cambio a nivel de visual basic la linea AddWithValue por Add(), y a nivel de sql waoo eso es nivel pro sinceramente me perdi cuando me dices los siguiente: "Se puede simplificar, empezando por asignar el valor correcto para el parámetro.." espero tu confirmacion

Comment: Si te fijas, en tu procedimiento original, tienes el parámetro declarado como varchar(max), cuando solo necesitas que sea varchar(18). Es importante evitar el MAX siempre que sea posible porque generan problemas de rendimiento. 
El resto del procedimiento es cambiar el cursor por una comparación usando la instrucción APPLY.

Comment: si olvide reemplarzar ese campo estoy trabajando con varchar(18), eso es evidencia de pruebas fallidas que he realizado, sabes lo que tengo dudas es con el Add() me da error al implementarlo me guias porfavor, de primera te digo que soy principiante en esto, gracias de antemano

Comment: Perdón, copié la sintaxis de C#, pero en VB se usan paréntesis en vez de corchetes para referenciar un parámetro en específico dentro del array de parametros. Fuera de eso, el resto no debería dar problemas.